# Google Apps script forms using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to get the **Edit URLs** and **pre-filled URLs** of html web forms using google apps script/javascript in the same way we can get the Edit URLs and pre-filled URLs of google forms?

How is it possible to get the pre-filled functionality with html forms instead of google forms?

Can someone please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using templated HTML, along with the doGet function used by all web apps, it could be done.

Refer to [URL Parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters) and [Pushing Variables to Templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates) from google's developer site.